# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2016

I am trying to import a datetime from PowerShell into a SQL Table.  It's the only thing stored in that table.

When I run this code:  (The value stored in the variable is: *11/19/2020 09:51:40.3244656*)

```
$location = 'path'
Set-Location $location

$c = Get-ChildItem 'path' | Sort { $_.LastWriteTime } | select -last 1 | foreach { $a = $_; $b = Get-Acl $_.FullName; Add-Member -InputObject $b -Name "LastWriteTime" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $a.LastWriteTime; $b }
$c.LastWriteTime

$date = $c.LastWriteTime
Function Get-Datetime([datetime]$Date = $date ) {
    $DT = Get-Date -Date $Date
    [string]$DateTime2 =  $DT.Month.ToString() + '/'
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.Day.ToString() + '/'
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.Year.ToString() + ' '
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.TimeOfDay.ToString()
    return $DateTime2
}

$finaldate = Get-Datetime

#$dateFormatted = $date -format
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "Server" -Database "db" -query "Update [server].[schema].[table] Set [columnName] = '$finaldate'"
```

I get this error:

```
Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

How can I get the Powershell command to update the table?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you *are* passing a date and time as a literal string, use a non-ambiguous format. There are only 2 in SQL Server: `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)`.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu.  How could I do that in this case?  (I updated the question to reflect what the variable currently is.)  I'm indifferent how I pass it, if there is a better way I'm open to it.

Comment: @JM1 `Get-Date <DateVariable> -Format yyyyMMdd` or `Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`

Comment: Thanks @NekoMusume.  When I do this:  Get-Date $finaldate -Format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, I still get the conversation failed error as well as the 'Get-Date : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'HH:mm:ss'' error

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the best at SQL, but it looks like the error says that one of your parameters are incorrect (sorry if I am stating the obvious), this is a different error than before meaning that the previous error is resolved? Try reviewing the syntax of `Invoke-SQLCommand`

Answer (score 0):

@NekoMusume helped me get to the answer to this specific question.  After adding this line, (modified from @NekoMusume's comment):  Thanks @NekoMusume! (If you want to answer, I'll mark it for you.)

> $finaldate = Get-Date $finaldate -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"

The code worked.  Final Working code

```
$location = 'path'
Set-Location $location

$c = Get-ChildItem 'path' | Sort { $_.LastWriteTime } | select -last 1 | foreach { $a = $_; $b = Get-Acl $_.FullName; Add-Member -InputObject $b -Name "LastWriteTime" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $a.LastWriteTime; $b }
$c.LastWriteTime

$date = $c.LastWriteTime
Function Get-Datetime([datetime]$Date = $date ) {
    $DT = Get-Date -Date $Date
    [string]$DateTime2 =  $DT.Month.ToString() + '/'
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.Day.ToString() + '/'
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.Year.ToString() + ' '
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.TimeOfDay.ToString()
    return $DateTime2
}

$finaldate = Get-Datetime
$finaldate = Get-Date $finaldate -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"

    
#$dateFormatted = $date -format
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "Server" -Database "db" -query "Update [server].[schema].[table] Set [columnName] = '$finaldate'"
```

Comment: If you are redefining `$finaldate`  with the previous value, you could make this one line: `$finaldate = Get-Date $(Get-Datetime) -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"`. It isn't too much of an eyesore because `Get-Datetime` is not that big of an expression.